# Alarm code in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have code the app with future Reminder by Toast notification , i can remind every times by BackgroundTask

But i want to reminder at one time in every day like : 4.00 PM every day

I search and get info about Alarm and Reminder are out of Windows Phone 8.1

So have another way ?

Sorry my bad English

Answer (score 3):

You can use a scheduled toast notification to fire a toast at a specific time. This doesn't require the app be running when the toast fires, only when the toast is scheduled.

You will need to schedule individual toasts for each day as there is no automatic repetition. If the user is likely to run the app frequently then you can schedule the next 30 days or so whenever the app runs. Another option is to set a MaintainanceTrigger background task to schedule the next 30 days every so often when the app is plugged in.

```
            // Today, 4:00pm
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dueTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 16, 0, 0);
        ToastNotifier toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();

        for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
        {
            dueTime.AddDays(1);
            XmlDocument toastXml = SetupMyToast(dueTime);

            ScheduledToastNotification scheduledToast = new ScheduledToastNotification(toastXml, dueTime);
            toastNotifier.AddToSchedule(scheduledToast);
        }
```

For more details see [Quickstart: Sending a toast notification (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868254.aspx) [and How to schedule a toast notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868224(v=win.10).aspx)