# Alarm Notification In Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to the windows phone development and i want to know how to achive the below notification in windows phone

[image]

as i no windows phone alarm and reminder classes has been removed from windows phone 8.1 tried toast and scheduled notification able to create a notification but i am unable to get the above. Please give me solution for this thanks

Regards,

Saleem Khan

Comment: Last time I checked it was not possible. You could make a WP8.1 Silverlight app though, which has the Alarm and Reminder classes.

Comment: i want to use timepicker and in silverlight app timepicker is not available, any solution on this would be a grate help

Comment: There is - in the [Windows Phone Toolkit](https://phone.codeplex.com/) (whish is a free toolkit by MS that almost everybody uses) or in the Telerik's [UI for Windows Phone](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) (which is $100 but has a lot of nice and customizable controls).

Comment: thanks yasen for ur reply and will try what u said. thanks a lot

Comment: @SaleemKhan were you able to achieve the same UI in the windows phone 8.1(RT) application?

Answer (score 5):

If you create the app using "Windows Phone" template (for example, "Hub App (Windows Phone)"), it's not possible to use reminders or alarms.

But you can use the Silverlight stack to create your app. For example, if you use "Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight)" as the starting point, you can access reminder and alarm functionality.

Here's a good tutorial on using alarms and reminders in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202965(v=vs.105).aspx

Here's more information about the differences between "Windows Phone" and "Windows Phone Silverlight" templates in Visual Studio:[In windows phone 8.1 what is the differance between Windows phone project and silverlight project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544762/in-windows-phone-8-1-what-is-the-differance-between-windows-phone-project-and-si)

Comment: thanks for replying sir, but i want to use a timepicker, as i know silverlight app doesnt have timepicker

Answer (score 2):

This can act as a solution if one doesn't want to switch from windows 8.1 phone app to silverlight n others

[Alarm code in Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989590/alarm-code-in-windows-phone-8-1)

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite